# change CSS for Growl

Tags: css, growl

I'm trying to change the location of my growl notification

I have a large notification which is on the top of my screen from left to right, and I would like to keep the seize but move the whole notification by the middle of the screen instead, or maybe a bit more at the button but not totally. (so I can still use my computer without dismissing the notification)

Here is the CSS :

```
body {
    margin: 0;}

#background {
    background-color: #000000;}

#icon {
    float: left;margin: auto 30px 99% 30px;}

#icon img {
    height: 128px;margin: 32px 0 0 0;width: 128px;}

#text {
    color: #FFFFFF;font: italic normal normal 30pt Futura;padding: 0 0 20px 0;}

#title {
    color: #FFFFFF;font: normal normal normal 60pt Futura;}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 3200px) {
    body { width: 3199px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2880px) and (max-device-width: 3199px) {
    body { width: 2879px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2560px) and (max-device-width: 2879px) {
    body { width: 2559px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2048px) and (max-device-width: 2559px) {
    body { width: 2047px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) and (max-device-width: 2047px) {
    body { width: 1919px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1600px) and (max-device-width: 1919px) {
    body { width: 1599px;}}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1440px) and (max-device-width: 1599px) {
    body { width: 1439px;}}



/*---:[ Low ]:-----------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes verylow {0% {} 100% {background-color: #414C22;}}
#verylow #background {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: verylow;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}



/*---:[ Moderate ]:------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes moderate {0% {} 100% {background-color: #B8A22B;}}
#moderate #background {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: moderate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}



/*---:[ High ]:----------------------*/
#high #background {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 129px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 129px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    width: 960px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 925 150, 1000, 1000 -800, 775, from(#47CC45), to(#000000))
}

#high body {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;width: 980px;}

#high #icon {
    margin: auto 20px 99% 20px;}

#high #icon img {
    margin: 0;}

#high #text {
    font: italic normal normal 20pt Futura;text-align: justify;width: 850px;}

#high #title {
    color: #47CC45;font: normal normal normal 30pt Futura;padding: 20px 0 0 0;}



/*---:[ Emergency ]:-----------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes emergency {0% {} 100% {background-color: #9C150B;}}
#emergency #background {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: emergency;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
```

What do I have to change, I keep playing around with all the @Media only line but I don't manage to have what I want